# Why Fullstory library makes scroll slower on Chrome browser?

Tags: angularjs, performance, google-chrome, onscroll

We use the Fullstory (www.fullstory.com) library to track the usage of our product, but we have problems on Chrome browser : when we scroll on desktop or mobile, it's 2 or 3 times slower than on other browers (for instance Safari or Firefox). 
Is it a Chrome API problem (onScroll ? ) or a Fullstory bug ? We use AngularJS as front-end framework, maybe this is an AngularJS <> Fullstory bug ?